# Anyway to prove the boolean algebra theories 9 and 10?

Tags: boolean-logic

I have a problem grasping the fact that `A + AB = A` and `A(A + B) = A`

Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: For the second, do you mean `A(1 + B) = A`?

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, look at the truth tables (1=true, 0=false):

```
"A" "B" "AB" "A+B" "A + AB" "A(A+B)"  
 0   0   0    0     0        0   
 0   1   0    1     0        0  
 1   0   0    1     1        1  
 1   1   1    1     1        1
```